# Mac Os X php56-fpm libpng error

Tags: php, macos, nginx, fastcgi

I'm not very good when it comes to managing libraries on mac os x. I'm running php56-fpm on mac and getting the following errors:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.9/sbin/php-fpm
  Reason: Incompatible library version: php-fpm requires version 34.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 29.0.0
/usr/local/opt/php56/sbin/php56-fpm: line 53: 38984 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $php_fpm_BIN --daemonize $php_opts
 failed
```

Obviously I have an old library of libpng installed. Normally I'd remove it, find an updated version of the library and install. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this on mac. I've tried uninstall and reinstalling with brew, but I keep grabbing the outdated libpng. How can I get the new updated version?